# Building CMAKE for cygwin

Tags: cmake, cygwin

This is my first time using both Cygwin and `cmake`, I'm trying to build a project but keep getting errors.

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/cmake: cannot execute binary file
```

The questions I have are, where should `cmake` be installed and how do I run it?

Where should my source code be?

Do I need anything extra to get `cmake` to work in Cygwin?

Here is a link to the project I am trying to run: (https://github.com/erinaceous/shadows)

Comment: How did you install the CMake which is present in `/usr/local/bin/cmake`?

Comment: @Angew I downloaded the binary distribution for linux "cmake-3.1.2-Linux-x86_64.sh"

Comment: You can't use Linux binaries with Cygwin, Cygwin is a different platform. Get CMake from your Cygwin package manager, or download its source code and build it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

`cmake` is available in the Cygwin net distribution.  You can install it with `setup-x86*.exe`; you should find it under the `Devel` category.

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin's mirrors are not always up-to-date.  To build your own from source for Cygwin (these instructions assume some version of cmake is already installed on your system, as is a compiler (eg. g++):

1. Download the latest (v3.4.1 at the time of this writing) source from [CMake.org/files](https://cmake.org/files/).  Be sure to enter the folder and also enter the cygwin folder within, and download the latest version (eg. https://cmake.org/files/v3.4/cygwin/cmake-3.4.1-1.tar.bz2)
2. From cygwin, **cd** to the folder where you downloaded the tar.bz2 file and type:

   ```
   tar xvjf cmake-{x.y.z}.tar.bz2 #for me, the actual filename was cmake-3.4.1-1.tar.bz2
   cd cmake-{x.y.z}
   ./configure
   make
   ```

from there, you'll find your binaries in the **./bin** folder.