# Build cmake for cygwin

Tags: cmake

[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28410889/building-cmake-for-cygwin)

Hello.

I want to build Cmake 3.0.0 by cygwin. But I don't understand what's libraries need to install before.
By default with `./configuration` it is impossible task.

Somebody know how it does?

Upd:
Sorry, `./configure` file

Comment: Did you try the steps in the readme (https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/tree/v3.0.0)?  I don't see `./configuration` there.

Comment: Yes, you are right